# Is Visual Studio 14 required to build MVC 6

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

Do I have to install Visual Studio 14 preview to build an MVC 6 app or can I do that using Visual Studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required. The new project system only exists in VS 2015. You can also build it via the command line without VS.